# Setting focus on an external react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React.  I'm converting a vanilla JS app to a React app.  When my vanilla app calls .focus() on the nav.timeline_context_menu element, the menu appears (due to some z-index manipulation). While converting to React, I'm having trouble figuring out how to target nav.timeline_context_menu element from the component that is supposed to trigger the .focus().

Desired outcome: if you right-click on a TimelineEvent component, it is supposed to trigger .focus() on the ContextMenu component.

This is what I have built so far.  I've considered using context, but I can't wrap my brain around how.  I'd appreciate your help.

Here is are the components:

**/App.js**

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Timeline />
        <ContextMenu />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

**/components/Timeline.js**

```
export default function Timeline(props){
    const [timelineEvents, setTimelineEvents] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData(){
            /* gets an array of TimelineEvent components */
            setTimelineEvents(await GetTimelineEvents()) 
        }

        fetchData()
    }, [])

    return (
        <section className="timeline">
            <ul>{timelineEvents}</ul>           
        </section>
    )
}
```

**/components/TimelineEvent.js**

```
export default function TimelineEvent(props){
    const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState(false)

    return (
        <li data-id={props.event.id} onContextMenu={
            e => {
                setIsFocused(true);
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }>
            <div className="wrapper">
                <div className="content">
                    <time>{props.event.injectTime}</time>
                    <span>{props.event.text}</span>
                </div>
                <div className="arrow"></div>
                <div className="balloon" draggable="true"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
    );
}
```

**/components/ContextMenu.js**

```
export default function ContextMenu(){
    return (
        <nav className="timeline_context_menu" tabIndex="0">
            <h1>Options</h1>
            <button className="btnEdit">Edit</button>
            <button className="btnNew">New Injection</button>
            <hr/>
            <button className="btnDelete">Delete</button>
        </nav>
     );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think when trying to do focus, the best to do here is create a ref to gain access to the dom node and use vanilla js to trigger focus

according to the docs  https://reactjs.org/docs/accessibility.html#focus-control

Comment: Why do you think it is the best way to do it?